# PHP Warning: mkdir(): No such file or directory PHP WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, mkdir

The code below is supposed to create a directory for the country (two letter code) if it doesn't exist and a directory based on the age group if it doesn't exist however whenever someone uploads an image it comes in as a broken image and isn't shown unless I precreate the directories. I checked the error log and it gives me the following warning:

> PHP Warning:  mkdir(): No such file or directory in /home/wppspeacepals/public_html/insertParentStudent.php on line 64
>
> PHP Warning:  mkdir(): No such file or directory in /home/wppspeacepals/public_html/insertParentStudent.php on line 70

```
 $user_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp-content/themes/wellness-
 pro/artis-images/".$get_Country->country."/".$age_group_label;
  if(!is_dir($user_path)){
    mkdir($user_path, 0777);
  }

  $user_id = $get_Country->prefix_char.$get_Country->registration_number;
  $user_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp-content/themes/wellness-pro/artis-images/".$get_Country->country."/".$age_group_label."/".$user_id;
  if(!is_dir($user_path)){
    mkdir($user_path, 0777);
  }
```

Comment: using `mkdir($user_path, 0777, true);` will create the necessary directories if they don't already exist.

Answer (score 0):

Message is clear.

1) Please check that you have this directories created

```
/wp-content/themes/wellness-pro/artist-images/
```

2) If **$get_Country->country** is not yet created, you will get this error. Try asking if **/wp-content/themes/wellness-pro/artis-images/".$get_Country->country** is there with **is_dir()**. If it is then create the last folder using **$age_group_label**. If not, you will have to create first the country folder and then the age group one.

Basically you cant create folder **two** by doing

```
mkdir /home/me/one/two
```

If you dont have folder **one** created. 
So, your code should validate that like this:

```
$user_path_country = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp-
content/themes/wellness-
pro/artis-images/".$get_Country->country;

$user_path_age = $user_path_country."/".$age_group_label;

if (!is_dir($user_path_country)):
mkdir($user_path_country, 0777);
else:
mkdir($user_path_age, 0777);
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the entire path except the last element (your `$age_group_label` value) exist already?  Ie, `.../artist-images/atlantis/`exists before you try to create `.../artist-images/atlantis/ancient`

To ensure, you can always use the recursive option for `mkdir()` - it is equivalent to using the `-p` option on *nix `mkdir`.

```
mkdir ( string $pathname [, int $mode = 0777 [, bool $recursive = FALSE [, resource $context ]]] )
```